# Process requests and validating API Response for correct data in Python

Tags: python, function, loops, python-requests, loopback

I want to send a bulk of requests using requests.futures library in python.

The problem is some of the requests are getting `Server Error` in API response with 200 ok status code.

I need to implement a fallback mechanism to resend the failed requests and get the actual data from server.

This is what I have implemented.

1. Code to send bulk data and getting bulk response using futures library

```
def sendBulkRequests(requestURLs):
    # this would send data to server
    return responseList
```

2. Validate Response

```
requestURLsToRetry = []
for i in range(len(responseList)):
    if 'sometext' not in responseList[i].text:
        requestURLsToRetry.append(requestURLs[i])
```

Now I need to resend `requestURLsToRetry` to `sendBulkRequests()`

```
responseListRetried = sendBulkRequests(requestURLsToRetry)
```

How do I append `responseListRetried` it to original `responseList` to be returned so the next code can process hoping the data returned is correct.

I might need to send sendBulkRequests() multiple times until all correct API responses are received and above condition 2 is verified with no issues.

Answer (score -1):

you cannnot change the list while you are iterating through it as it has to be fixed length. You could just iterate over the second list, or once the first process is finished and you have the list of failed requests just set list1 = listOfFailedRequests and iterate over list1 again with the previously defined function

Comment: and how do i merge it with the initial (first) list? I might have to perform this in loop for 5-6 times and would need to merge all newly created sub lists to main list with the exact index of failed responses.